# ADF LOV Not Refreshing

Tags: oracle-adf

I have an interesting situation. Working on an 11.1.1.3 ADF Application.

I have an editable table, which uses an LOV. The respective LOV has a maintenance page, where we populate a database table with data that the LOV uses.

If i'm inserting new records into the LOV Database Table, the corresponding LOV does not get those changes. However, if there is an UPDATE of existing records, it seems to work ok.

It appears the iterator is not updating. Because if i start up a new application session in a new browser window, i'll see the new changes.

The LOV doesn't have it's own iterator in the Page Bindings (Its using a View Accessor in my view object), so i'm not sure how to tell the iterator to refresh or executeQuery()...

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, my only solution is this. I don't like it, but it works...

Exposed View Row Impl class, and included accessors on my Editable ADF Table's View Object. This way i have programmatic access to my accessors that run the LOV.

Then i located my view accessor, getter method. And told it to re-execute the query. Worked like a charm:

```
public RowSet getAllSmsModules() {
  RowSet rs = (RowSet)getAttributeInternal(SMSMODULESALL);
  rs.executeQuery();
  return rs;
    //return (RowSet)getAttributeInternal(ALLSMSMODULES);
}
```

Comment: Have you created SMSMODULESALL because the accessor name seems to be ALLSMSMODULES. I am also facing the same problem. But after applying this solution also , it's not working